# Way to disable new logins when using accounts-google

Tags: meteor

I am using accounts-ui with accounts-google. I'd like to continue to allow existing users to login with accounts-google but I want to prevent new users from being able to create an account.

I have not been able to find a way to accomplish this. Has anyone implemented something like this or user registrations that require approval?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to disable new account creation in general, it's simple:

```
Accounts.validateNewUser(function() {
    return false;
});
```

Documentation: [`validateNewUser`](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_validatenewuser).

If you want to allow new registrations i.e. with password, but not with google, use the same method but in the validation function check if `user.profile` has inserted info from google.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out and report back.